# Horizontal tab, get text value from a form within Navigation Button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the home page, horizontal navigation from which includes many navigation buttons, under NavigationButton7 I have employeesfrm, and I need to navigate Next or previous while I am in the home form.

The ID is embedded within the employeesFrm, so the VBA code when on unload of the employeesfrm, not on the home form, is not giving the right ID while I am on the home form.

I have tried Froms!home!navigationSubform!ID, but this will give error because any ID within any other NavigationButton8 or 9 will give another result, and I am not interested to know the ID of the other forms in other buttons.

My concern is to have a link between the ID within the employeesfrm and the Home form text.

Nothing is working from the below

```
Dim MyIDS As Integer

' this is giving only the first ID number all the time.
MyIDS = Me.ID 

' this is giving error.
MyIDS = Forms![Home]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![employeesfrm]![ID]

' this is giving error.
MyIDS = Forms![Home]![NavigationSubform]![Navigationform]![studentsfrm]![ID] 

' this one works but if I am on another Navigation button,
' lets say 8 not 7, I am not interested in the number.
MyIDS = Forms![Home]![NavigationSubform].Form![ID]
```

I need this number, for my bookmark, it works fine if I am directly on the employeesfrm, but not on the home form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/320x2.jpg)

Comment: You should use Tab control instead of navigation form control. Might better suit your needs.

Comment: i can't change the design now...right?

Comment: If you want, you can change design. It is quite common to iterate through design while reaching your goal to achieve something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to achieve, but how about having an unbound text box called EmpID on the Home form, and then in the OnCurrent event of the Employees form set

```
Me.Parent!EmpID = ID
```

If you're using this to try and get back to the same record you were on before you went off to look at a different subform then you would also need a way to detect that you're coming back to this subform, otherwise the OnCurrent event will just set you back to the first record again. So you perhaps need a check box (chkGoToBookmark, default value False) on the main form so that NavigationButton7 (this is what loads the Employees subform, right?) can tick this box. Then the Employees form's OnCurrent event would be:

```
If Me.Parent!chkGoToBookmark = True And Not IsNull(Me.Parent!EmpID) Then
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "ID=" & Me.Parent!EmpID
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
Else
    Me.Parent!EmpID = ID
End If
```

Note that if you're on the Employees form directly then any references to `Me.Parent` will cause an error, so you may want to trap this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck, I am sharing my solution with All, however, Horizontal Form is pain, really go to Tab control instead,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I was stuck, I am sharing my solution with All, however, Horizontal Form is pain, really go to Tab control instead, my issue was the bookmark, it was easy dealing with bookmark if you are on the same form, but when the form is inside the main (home) form which is navigation control then it is not easy, what I have done is the following:
created a txt on the main form, called Txtv, this will host my ID from the form inside my horizontal button, and on the unload and load events I used the below,

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Parent!txtv) Then

    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("bookmarktb", dbOpenDynaset)
    With rs
        .FindFirst "[Variable] = 'CustomerIDLast'"
        If .NoMatch Then
            .AddNew        'Create the entry if not found.
                ![Variable] = "CustomerIDLast"
                ![Values] = Me.Parent!txtv
                ![Description] = "Last customerID, for form " & Me.Name
            .Update
        Else
            .Edit          'Save the current record's primary key.
                ![Values] = Me.Parent!txtv
            .Update
        End If
    End With
    rs.Close
End If
Set rs = Nothing
```

Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim varID As Variant
    Dim strIIZ As String

```
varID = DLookup("Values", "bookmarktb", "[Variable] = 'CustomerIDLast'")
If IsNumeric(varID) Then
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst "[ID] = " & strIIZ & varID & strIIZ
        If Not .NoMatch Then
            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
    End With
End If
```

End Sub

don't forget please to add on current event of the form me.parent.txtv=ID
so it will update the ID with the main form.

I think I will suffer after splitting the data base, as i have heard the findfirst will not work fine if database is split.
I am not sure but it should work fine with the consolidated batabase,